# Как отправить письмо в Python с индексированным текстом

Tags: python, html

Мне с помощью питона нужно отправить Письмо. Проблема в том что текст не индексируется и приходит в таком же виде. Подскажите что делать

```
def mail_send(target,text):

sender = "тут будет почта"
password = "ага щас же так и сказал"
message = '''
<b>Hello!</b>
{text}
'''

server = smtp.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.com')
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.ehlo(sender)
server.login(sender, password)
server.auth_plain()
server.sendmail(sender, target, message)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Что значит "не индексируется"? вы уверены, что правильно используете слова? И смените уже никнейм.

Comment: не хочу и не буду меня никнейм :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def mail_send(target,text):
    sender = "тут будет почта"
    password = "ага щас же так и сказал"
    message = f'''
    <b>Hello!</b>
    {text}
    '''

server = smtp.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.com')
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.ehlo(sender)
server.login(sender, password)
server.auth_plain()
server.sendmail(sender, target, message)
server.quit()
```

используйте префикс `f`, для того чтобы форматировать текст.